# Slot Machine Uses Fake Money Still Illegal?

Tags: gambling, currency

So I have a friend who wants to build a slot-machine or similar device for an event operating in Connecticut. According to them it will only be operable with a certain type of fake currency (like Monopoly money). I understand that slot machines are illegal for the average citizen to own in CT, but I haven't seen anything that would tell me if this money changes the legality.

Some clarifications: 
The fake currency does have a flexible real-world value to allow people who want to purchase goods such as food (NOT gamble) to do so at events regardless of if they have any in-game currency. I have never seen or heard of anyone exchanging this coin for real money or vice versa. The coins are printed by players for the game. They are 'backed' by a typically goods based service provided by players, such as prop creation or art commissions. There isn't an official value assessment attached to these associations, it is based mostly on reputation and presence.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This is one of those "It's complicated.  Very complicated.  Talk to a lawyer." things.

Comment: Not worth an answer, but I have been to a casino (Harrah's at Stateline NV) that had a childs casino in the basement.  This had metal disks that could be bought, put in machines with a random chance of getting more back, and exchanged for goods.  Children were allowed to play.  I was surprised, but someone must have decided that was not gambling.

Comment: Hello Laura!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our tour page, linked at the bottom of this page.